# Enqueue new login style sheet

Tags: login, wp-enqueue-style

i tried to enqueue a new login stylesheet called login_styles.css.

This is the code i have used:

```
function my_logincustomCSSfile() {
    wp_enqueue_style('login-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/login_styles.css');
}
add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_logincustomCSSfile');
```

Its placed in my child-themes functions.php.

The css file is totally empty. How do i go about this?

The file is placed in same folder as functions.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `get_template_directory_uri()`, that's for your parent theme's directory, with `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` since you want to target the file within the child theme's directory.

Or better yet, just use `get_theme_file_uri( 'login_styles.css' )` if you want to search for it, first in the child theme's directory, else in the parent theme's directory.

Comment: That `get_theme_file_uri()` was something I was looking for a long time. Gracious be!

Comment: yes it's handy, more flexible and I like that it takes the file name as an input argument.